# How to boost speed of Java EE application

Tags: java, glassfish, java-7, java-ee-6

My application has the following structure :

> Glassfish as server and Java EE 6 structure (JSF + EJB + JPA).

I have a function that includes this code

```
public boolean function1(type value)
{
 boolean result = false;

  if()
  {
   .......
  }
  else
  {
   .........
  }
  return result ;
}

public void mainfunction(List<type> Listvalues)
{
 for(int i=0;i<Listvalues.size;i++)
 {
  Listvalues.get(i).setparametre(function1(Listvalues.g(i)))
 }
}
```

when i execute the mainfunction with a list that has a size > 100000 it takes 10 min.

my question is if my laptop configuration increased is the time of execution  reduced and by how much? and which parameter in the configuration of my laptop needs to be changed and by what? does it depend on the JDK too?

> my laptop configuration : intel core i7-2670QM CPU @2.20 GHz (8 CPUs)
>   Ram 4 gb windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give an answer without further details. From the little I see, I can suggest:

- What does function1 do? Does it contain any loop that depend on value? If it's linear wrt its parameter (i.e., it runs in approximately constant time), then you can improve performance by migrating on a faster CPU. If the program is consuming memory (caching etc), then you should try to give the JVM more memory (http://tinyurl.com/8ccrzwo)
- Where does Listvalues come from? Does it wrap database records? If yes, where is the database? If it's running on your PC, probably you'll improve performance by upgrading the CPU, and/or giving more memory to the DB server (or even changing max thread parameters). If it's on an external server, there isn't much you can do on your client side (apart from checking the connection/bandwidth)

Finally, the only major improvement that I can guess from your code is to try a parallel (i.e., multi-thread version of it), but, as I said, it's hard to say more, without details). A minor improvement might come from rewriting your code this way:

```
for ( Type item: listValues )
  item.setParameter ( function1 ( item ) );
```

This avoids to invoke List.get() twice (which is slightly expensive), most importantly, it iterates over the list via Collection.iterator(), which, if you have a LinkedList, is significantly faster than using the index.

Note that I've also renamed your variables and types according to Java conventions (and English grammar).

EDIT: from a comment below, I realise, I should have mentioned the general question, how to evaluate the performance of a program and how can it be improved? First of all, you should acquire knowledge of common algorithms and branches of mathematics, such as graph theory or operations research. There is also a computational complexity theory, which allows you to deal with algorithm analysis and optimisation (http://tinyurl.com/q52zxs2).

Comment: Firstly thank you for the answer .Secondly i didnt write more details because my goal is to not optimaze  the function but to understand even if with an optimazed code is the material give a difference in time execution and if for example my liste size became huge like 1000000000 and i need an answer in max 10 min what can i do ? its impossible to reduce the time ??or i need an other advanced materiel can execute this function in less then 10 min.

Comment: Please see the addition I made to my answer. Apart from the general case, it really depends on your function. In general, a program that runs at a given speed on a given computer, can run faster on a more powerful computer. But, this is not always true, for instance, if it is really badly written and contains blocking conditions, or if it scales badly (i.e., its performance degrades quickly with the list size), it will hang or be slow even on the most powerful computer in the universe.

Answer (score 0):

looping over 100,000 objects in java even on a slow processor will not take 10 minutes. What you need to do is determine what in your code is causing the slowness. It isn't the looping or the if/else statements you posted. As zakmck suggested, looking at database or IO operations will yield the best results. Memory and execution are fast, but disk, io, and datasources are slow.